# Dramatic worker is shutting down with time limit exceeded error

Tags: dramatiq

When I'm running a worker, it is shutting down with an error "Time limit exceeded". How to increase the time limit of worker.

Answer (score 1):

By default dramatiq has a default actor time limit of 10 minutes, which means that any actor running for longer than 10 minutes is killed with a TimeLimitExceeded error.
To increase the time limit, add a time_limit argument to the actor in milliseconds.
@actor(time_limit=60000)